# What do you think of using emojis in the subject line of a cold call email?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, recruitment, email

I’m a recent Electrical Engineering graduate who’s currently looking for a job. I have been sending cold call emails but getting no responses. I’m thinking it is because my email doesn’t have a unique subject line (usually I use: A Job Opportunity at XYZ). I’m wondering if it would be professional to use emojis in the subject line to get my email noticed by HR representatives. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I wouldnt use emojis, but you are right, you need to stand out in your subject line... In all honesty, it would probably serve you better to call companies instead of emailing them. They cant ignore you as easily on the phone then they can on an email.

Comment: @ZoeHowlett I am not in favor of call. I feel it would be hard to call companies asking for a job. They’ll most probably ask me to send an email with my resume and wait for them to contact me.

Comment: Totally agree, i dislike phone calls as well. But what you get from a phone call to HR is the recognition when they read your email they may think 'oh yes, I talked to that person' and pay more attention to your email...

Comment: Overall, I say no to emojis as it isnt professional, but Google some better more eye catching subject line.

Comment: What is your location? Couldn't you just apply for a job online instead of sending cold emails?

Comment: @jcmack I sure can. But cold calls are for unadvertised jobs. If the job is posted, I apply online. Otherwise, I send a cold call email.

Comment: I think asking what a "cold call" email should look like, rather than focusing on one thing you can change about it, would make for a better question. Although your proposed subject is quite formal - sometimes that's appropriate, but in many cases, especially if their work culture is casual, you'd probably have more luck showing some emotion in the subject ("I'd love to work for you!"). But I would expect such emails to not work about 99% of the time, assuming you checked their website first to see if they have openings and didn't find any.

Comment: @ZoeHowlett Unless you have a number of a specific person, it's seems unlikely that you'd actually be able to get the person who'll actually be reviewing job applications on the phone in most companies. I doubt a receptionist would do anything more than tell you to apply through the website.

Comment: @Lod - I wouldn't expect that there would be a meaningful number of unadvertised jobs that a new graduate would be suitable for.  If a company is looking for junior people, they're going to advertise.  A company might not advertise some senior jobs if doing so would cause issues (i.e. you don't advertise for a new CIO if you haven't fired the old one, you don't advertise for a machine vision specialist if you want to keep your self-driving car plans under wraps), because there is an internal candidate that they want to put in the position, etc.

Comment: @Dukeling There are plenty advices on how cold call emails should look like. I want my email to stand out from the subject line and I thought of using emojis. But I’m not sure if that’s a good idea that’s why I’m asking for opinions. Regarding the availability of jobs, I know most jobs for fresh graduate are unadvertised jobs. Since HR usually ask universities for a list, find graduates through career fairs, etc... The emails I send are either to an HR representative I got from connections or Linkedin or to the careers inquiries or talent pool email I find in the website.

Comment: @JustinCave Again as I said in the above comment, a lot of the fresh graduate jobs are unadvertised ones (by unadvertised I mean are not posted on the website). I’ve already went to several interviews for jobs that are unadvertised through my university’s career development office. There are companies that I would like to work for but I cannot find something for fresh graduate on their website, that’s why I send the cold call emails.

Comment: Are you going to interviews for jobs that are advertised through your university rather than on the company web site?  If so, that's very different from what "unadvertised" would normally mean.  A company might recruit from a particular set of universities.  It might post jobs on Monster/ Dice/ Craigslist/ etc. rather than (or instead of) posting it on their web site.  That's not an unadvertised job, though, so it would generally make more sense to look in these aggregator sites rather than sending cold emails to HR.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes. One interview was in a career fair that was open to all students from any university. Another two were through the career office. Regrading the aggregator websites, I couldn’t find jobs in my country. Anyways what I’m trying to say is that cold calls emails usually work here, but only if you get noticed.

Comment: _"A Job Opportunity at XYZ"_ looks more like a spam/phishing subject to me than making clear that you are looking for a job.

Comment: Oh I just ignore these types of cold emails for unlisted jobs. If you add emojis, I'll block you too. I find spammers tend to use emojis to disarm you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @jcmack well emojis are now used for marketing purposes and they still look legit.

Comment: @Lod That's actually the reason I block those. I don't want to be "marketed" to. Spammers and marketers both want your money one way or another.

Comment: @Lod I'm not sure what I'd use, but your example subject sounds like what a bad recruiter would send, so I'd likely mark it as junk without even reading. Add in emojis, and it is a guaranteed mark it as junk. The fact marketing departments use it is not an excuse, I just consider that an easier identification for spam, and I know a lot of people do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, job inquiry emails are not simply disregarded. It's just that they often prefer to not answer at all, rather than answering negatively. Cold call emails mean that there's usually not a position they could put you in. You being a recent graduate means you probably don't have enough experience to make you stand out against other potential employees, so I wouldn't be surprised if you're mostly not hearing back from them. I know it's frustrating, but unfortunately that's just how things are lately.

That said, I think emojis in the subject line could make your email look unprofessional to several companies, so it's generally not a good idea. Not to mention that you might get caught in badly designed spam filters.

Your initial thought, to make the subject of your email stand out a bit, is good. If you haven't already done so, you might also want to try working on your CV with someone more experienced to make it stand out as well, or work on your cover letter trying to convince them that you're a good fit for them, etc.

Good luck in your job search, hope you find a good company soon!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your nice and understanding response. I’m just sharing an idea I had in mind since emojis are now used extensively for marketing purposes. And you’re right I don’t have much experience in job seeking, but I’ve shared my cv and cover letter with experienced professionals and have made sure they’re standing out and truly representative of my skills. However as I mentioned earlier, I was worried my problem was in the fact that perhaps my emails are not read in the first place due to the subject line.

Answer (score 5):

> I’m wondering if it would be professional to use emojis in the subject
>   line

No, it would not be professional. Emojis are mostly for scams and children - not for professionals seeking jobs.